# Estimator using MLE, Maximizing Median Likelihood and Moments of Data

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, machine-learning, maximum-likelihood

There are N i.i.d. (independent and identically distributed) samples drawn from the distribution with the probability density function:
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{2x}{\theta^2},  & \text{if $0 \geq x \geq \theta$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Three Researchers want to use three different approaches to estimate parameter $\theta$

- Researcher A estimates $\theta$ by first computing the probability density function of
  observing the data given $\theta \rightarrow P(X_1,...,X_N; \theta)$, then maximizing this w.rt. $\theta$ (Maximum Likelihood Estimation). Call this estimate of $\theta$ as $R_a$.
- Researcher B estimates the median of this distribution by maximizing the likelihood of
  the median. Call this estimate as $R_b$
- Researcher C uses the theoretical moment and the sample moment of the data to estimate
  it. Call this estimate $R_c$.

(1) Please calculate $R_a, R_b, R_c$

(2) Which estimate is better? Please justify your conclusion taking bias and variance
into consideration.

Solution:
(1) Using similar approach as described by following solution: [MLE for Uniform $(0,\theta)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2941187/mle-for-uniform-0-theta)

$$ R_a = X_{(N)} :=\max_{1 \leq i \leq N}X_i $$
$$ R_b = X_{(N)} :=\max_{1 \leq i \leq N}X_i $$
because median = $\frac{\theta}{\sqrt{2}}$ and maximizing Median is same as maximizing $\theta$ or **MLE**

---

Now, I want guidance on 2 of the following issues:

1. If my answers and logic for the first part are correct?
2. Can you point me in the right direction with the approach for the second part?