# MLE: given density $p_{\theta}(x) = \frac{1}{\theta}, \text{where } 0 \leq x \leq \theta.$

Tags: maximum-likelihood

Given: $\theta>0$, $X_1,...,X_n$ i.i.d. RV with

> $p_{\theta}(x) = \frac{1}{\theta}, \text{where } 0 \leq x \leq \theta$

and

> $p_{\theta}(x)=0, \text{else.}$

In the given exercise the MLE solution $L_X(\sigma)$ is

> $L_X(\sigma)=\frac{1}{\sigma^n}1_{\{0\leq X_{(0)} \leq X_{(n)} \leq
> \sigma \}}$

with the order statistic, which I unterstand. But then they claim $\hat\theta = X_{(n)}$ if $\theta\geq X_{(n)}$ and zero else, without a lot of explanation. Can you explain me this solution?

I see that $\frac{1}{\sigma^n}$ is strictly decreasing for $\sigma>0$. But it seems to me that we cannot conclude without knowing if the maximum of the RV is $X_{(n)} < 1$ or $X_{(n)}\geq1$.

Comment: Since $X_{(n)}\le\theta$ almost surely, the MLE is simply $\hat\theta=X_{(n)}$. Does this answer your question? [How do you differentiate the likelihood function for the uniform distribution in finding the M.L.E.?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649678/how-do-you-differentiate-the-likelihood-function-for-the-uniform-distribution-in)

Comment: Indeed! Thank you very much, I did not find this treat by myself. The intuitive suggestion of the given [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/649678/how-do-you-differentiate-the-likelihood-function-for-the-uniform-distribution-in) helped a lot!